# how to check if two dimensional array is empty

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

how can I check if this two dimentinal array is empty?

this is  my code :

```
      String[][] user = new String[5][3];

        System.out.print(user.length);

            if (user.length == 5 ){
                System.out.print("\n empty");
            }

        for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
            System.out.print(" " + user[0][j]+ "\n");
        }
```

and the output is :

```
5
 empty null null null
```

Does anyone have an ide about my situation?

Comment: Some code is missing isn't it? How do you get so much output from at most one `System.out.println`?

Comment: Define "empty". Do you mean `null` or `""`?

Comment: I think you don't send complete your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are misunderstanding something in Java I think. When you write  :

```
String[][] user = new String[5][3];

user.length will always be 5 and 

user[0].length = user[1].length = ... = user[5].length = 3
```

If you want to check if all value in your array are emty you can do something like :

```
boolean notNull = false;
for(String[] array : user){
    for(String val : array){
      if(val!=null){
        notNull=true;
        break;
      }
    }
}
if(notNull){
  System.out.println("Array not empty)";
}else{
     System.out.println("Array empty");
}
```

Another solution would be to use [`Arrays.deepEquals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[]%29) :

```
String[][] user = new String[5][3];
String[][] emptyReferenceForComparison= new String[5][3];
Arrays.deepEquals(user, emptyReferenceForComparison); // return true
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Apache Commons Lang3. In this library exist utility for working with arrays.
Name of the class is `ArrayUtils`. For sample:

```
    String[][] user = new String[5][3];
    for(String[] nestedArray : user)
        if(ArrayUtils.isEmpty(nestedArray))
            System.out.println("Is empty");
```

Apache Commans Lang3 is good utility. 
see [**here**](http://search.yahoo.com/r/_ylt=A0oG7k_sJEpPIycAWq9XNyoA;_ylu=X3oDMTE1bmlybDZzBHNlYwNzcgRwb3MDMQRjb2xvA2FjMgR2dGlkA1ZJUDA1MV8yMDU-/SIG=11jg842tm/EXP=1330287980/%2a%2ahttp://commons.apache.org/lang/) for more informations.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes during competitive programming problems, in order to handle the corner case some code like in the snippet below would be necessary. Just checking `matrix.length==0` will not work since it gives only whether the row is empty but there might be a column present in it.

```
if(matrix.length < 1 || matrix[0].length < 1) {
    return true; //empty
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. I am here to help :) Thanks for your feedback.